# In AngularFire how to keep track of data is "In flight"?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm working on chatting application in firebase and angular. When I send message using `$scope.send(message)` function it's directly upend to `$scope.messages` array because of three-way binding of angularfire. It's initially stored in locally and sync with server in background. I want to keep track message's status if it's sync with server or not. AngularFire's `$push` method has callback when it's sync with server. But I'm getting no clue of how to keep track of data is "In flight" ( Not synched with server but added in angular `scope` variable.)

```
var Ref = new Firebase('FIREBASE_APP_URL');
var ref = Ref.child('messages');

$scope.messages= $firebaseArray(ref).orderByChild('createdAt').limitToLast(10));

$scope.send = function(message) {
      $scope.messages.$add(message).then(function(ref) {
      var id = ref.key();
      console.log("added record with id " + id);
      console.log($scope.messages.$indexFor(id)); // returns location in the array
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$firebaseArray` object is not involved in any three-way data binding. That is limited to `$firebaseObject`s `.bindTo()` method.

What happens when you call `$add()` is that a local `child_added` event is immediately raised and the `$firebaseArray` updates its internal data based on that. This is how all Firebase clients work, not just AngularFire, and it is part of why Firebase appears to work instantaneous.

If you want to know when the item was added *on the server*, you can use the promise that `$add()` returns. When that promise resolves, the data has been committed on the server.

From the [AngularFire documentation for `$add()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata):

> This method returns a promise which is resolved after data has been saved to the server.

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
list.$add({ foo: "bar" }).then(function(ref) {
  var id = ref.key();
  console.log("added record with id " + id);
  list.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
});
```

Comment: Actually my question is opposite. I figured out to check if data is synced with server. But I'm stuck on how to track data that has been added to locally and yet to update on server. I want to add `sending` status if data is yet to update on server.

Comment: That is exactly what the promise returned by `$add()` does. If you want to track which data is still "in flight", you'd add the data to a "pending writes" array before you all `$add()` and remove if from that array when the promise resolves.

Comment: actually that's where I'm having trouble to keep track of data is still "In flight", because on call of `$add()` method, angular adds data into array.